# How to store array of Object in database in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

My schema is

```
  branch_name: {type: String},
  semester_name: [{
    semester: {type: String},
    subject: [{
        subject_name: {type: String}
     }]
  }]
```

and the result coming from front-end is -

```
{ 
   branch: 'it',
   semester: '5',
   subject: [
             { subject_name: 'math' }, 
             { subject_name: 'bio' } 
            ]
  }
```

my Api for inserting code is-

```
   const new_branch = new Branch({
      branch_name: data.branch,
      semester_name: [{
        semester: data.semester,
        subject: [{
          subject_name: data.subject.subject_name
        }]
      }]
    });

    new_branch.save((err,result) =>{
      console.log(err);
      console.log(result);
    });
```

How to store the subject_name.

I tried many ways but still not working

Comment: Kindly post your insert code.

Comment: And try using $push.

Comment: try this `const new_branch = new Branch(data)`

Comment: @SyedKashanAli Does $push works with inserting code

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet , It's not working.

Comment: if your data keys are same as your model keys then it definitely work...

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet answer is correct try that.

Comment: @Rupesh $push works with update only but you can insert with update also using upsert:true.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet, yes, it is working, Thnx